# Add users with specific permissions for a library in sharepoint

Tags: permissions

Good Morning All,

I have one issue in sharepoint. I have multiple libraries and I created new user with permission "Read", I want him to read only the documents in 2 libraries and I assigned him to them. Now, he can only read the documents in these 2 libraries but still can view and edit other libraries !!

Where is the problem ?, and how can I debug it ?!
Any suggestions ?!

Best Regards

Comment: And you are doing this through code or gui?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that for some reason your new user is also part of the site members group. You need to edit this group to remove the new user.